# Выдает ошибку Python: TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, dict

Выдает ошибку Python: TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'.
Задача такова, надо найти топ-3 ученика с высшим баллом

Входные данные:

```
students_avg_scores = {'Max': 4.964, 'Eric': 4.962, 'Peter': 4.923, 'Mark': 4.957, 'Julie': 4.95, 'Jimmy': 4.973, 'Felix': 4.937, 'Vasya': 4.911, 'Don': 4.936, 'Zoi': 4.937}
```

Мой код:

```
def make_report_about_top3(std):
    std = students_avg_scores
    aa = sorted(dict(std))
    return aa

print(make_report_about_top3(std=students_avg_scores[:4]))
```

Помогите пожалуйста, что здесь надо исправить?

Comment: А зачем вы делаете `dict(std)`?? Вообще код очень странный, вы хоть чуть-чуть разберитесь, что вы вообще делаете в этом коде и зачем.

Comment: Да, я понимаю что здесь делаю и что хочу поделить,
Проблема не актуальна, так как уже её исправил. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def make_report_about_top3(students_avg_scores):
   avg = sorted(students_avg_scores.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)[:3]
   dc = dict(avg)

print(make_report_about_top3(students_avg_scores))
```

Comment: Автор вопроса уже нашел решение, поэтому не понятно зачем вы дали ответ.

Comment: @NickolayChistov, никто не запрещает дать ответ, если вопрос не закрыт. Ответы даются для автора и для сообщества. Если автор нашел решение, но не оформил его ответом - с точки зрения сообщества ответа у вопроса нет.